# Showing that $\frac{x}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$ is locally integrable

Tags: integration, lebesgue-integral

Let $F:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ be

$$F(x,y)=\frac{x}{(x^2+y^2)^2}, \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \ \ (x,y)\neq(0,0))$$

I was trying to show that $F$ is locally integrable.

[My idea]

1 )  $\ \ $ Show that F is integrable at $B(0,1)$(open ball with center at $(0,0)$ and ratio 1).

to this end, we notice that for all $\epsilon\in (0,1)$, $F$ is  integrable at $B_\epsilon(0,1):=B(0,1)- B[0,\epsilon]$  with $\int_{B_\epsilon(0,1)}F(x,y)dxdy=0$ (using polar coordinates, for example)

Then $\int_{B(0,1)}F(x,y)dxdy=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}$$\int_{B_\epsilon(0,1)}F(x,y)dxdy=0$

2 ) $ \ \ $ As $F$ is continuous in $\mathbb{R}^2-(0,0)$, then $F$ is locally integrable in $\mathbb{R}^2-(0,0)$.

For 1), and 2) , can I conclude that $F$ is locally integrable?

Answer (score 3):

$F$ is locally integrable 0n $\Bbb R^2$ if $\int_K|F|<\infty$ for every compact $K\subset\Bbb R^2$. Since
$$
\int_{0< x^2+y^2\le1}F(x,y)\,dxdy=\int_0^1\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{|r\cos\theta|}{r^4}\,r\,dr=4\int_0^1\frac{dr}{r^2}=\infty,
$$
$F$ is not locally integrable on $\Bbb R^2$.

However, it is true that $F$ is integrable on $\{x^2+y^2\ge\epsilon\}$ for all $\epsilon>0$ and that
$$
\int_{ x^2+y^2\ge\epsilon}F(x,y)\,dxdy=0.
$$

Comment: I got it. I was doing the integral of $F$ instead of $|F|$. Thanks a lot @JuliánAguirre